# How to add meta data to UDP stream in python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, udp, video-streaming

I have client server application which is sending udp server from one client to other in python. In the UDP stream I am sending a video by reading the video from disk using CV2 and then sending it using UDP.

I want to add some meta data along with the video stream. I want to add the frame number, timestamp, video name, playback time and the starting time to the video stream.

How can I do the same. I have created multiple UDP sockets which are managed by using threads.

The following is the code for sender

```
import cv2
import socket
import math
import pickle
import sys

max_length = 65000
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 6000

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("input2.mp4")
print(cap)
ret, frame = cap.read()
print(ret)
while ret:
    # compress frame
    retval, buffer = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)

    if retval:
        # convert to byte array
        buffer = buffer.tobytes()
        # get size of the frame
        buffer_size = len(buffer)
        print(buffer_size)
        num_of_packs = 1
        if buffer_size > max_length:
            num_of_packs = math.ceil(buffer_size/max_length)

        frame_info = {"packs":num_of_packs}

        # send the number of packs to be expected
        print("Number of packs:", num_of_packs)
        sock.sendto(pickle.dumps(frame_info), (host, port))
        
        left = 0
        right = max_length

        for i in range(num_of_packs):
            print("left:", left)
            print("right:", right)

            # truncate data to send
            data = buffer[left:right]
            left = right
            right += max_length

            # send the frames accordingly
            sock.sendto(data, (host, port))
    
    ret, frame = cap.read()

print("done")
```

The following is the code for server

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2
import socket
import math
import pickle
import sys
import numpy as np
import json


def sendToClient(threadNum,hostRec,portRec,hostSend,portSend):
    max_length = 65540
    sockRec = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sockRec.bind((hostRec,portRec))
    sockSend = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  
    while True:
        data, address = sockRec.recvfrom(max_length)
        print("Received data on "+str(threadNum))
        sockSend.sendto(data,(hostSend,portSend))

def main():
    host = '0.0.0.0'
    ports = [6000,6001,6002]
    
    thread1 = Thread(name = 'Thread-1',target = sendToClient, args=('thread-1',host,ports[0],'127.0.0.1',7000))
    thread2 = Thread(name = 'Thread-2',target = sendToClient, args=('thread-2',host,ports[1],'127.0.0.1',7001))
    thread3 = Thread(name = 'Thread-3',target = sendToClient, args=('thread-3',host,ports[2],'127.0.0.1',7002))

    thread1.daemon = True
    thread2.daemon = True
    thread3.daemon = True

    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread3.start()

    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()
    thread3.join()

main()
```

The following is the code for receiver

```
from concurrent.futures import thread
import cv2
import socket
import pickle
import numpy as np
from threading import Thread

def display(threadNum,host,port,videoPlayerInfo):
    max_length = 65540
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind((host, port))

    frame_info = None
    buffer = None
    frame = None

    print("-> waiting for connection on thread "+ str(threadNum))

    while True:
        data, address = sock.recvfrom(max_length)
        print("Received Data from "+str(threadNum))
        if len(data) < 100:
            frame_info = pickle.loads(data)

            if frame_info:
                nums_of_packs = frame_info["packs"]

                for i in range(nums_of_packs):
                    data, address = sock.recvfrom(max_length)

                    if i == 0:
                        buffer = data
                    else:
                        buffer += data

                frame = np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype=np.uint8)
                frame = frame.reshape(frame.shape[0], 1)

                frame = cv2.imdecode(frame, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
                frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
                
                if frame is not None and type(frame) == np.ndarray:
                    cv2.imshow(videoPlayerInfo, frame)
                    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
                        break
                    
    print("goodbye from "+str(threadNum))

def main():
    host = "0.0.0.0"
    ports = [7000,7001,7002]
    thread1 = Thread(name = 'Thread-1',target = display, args=('thread-1',host,ports[0],'player1'))
    thread2 = Thread(name = 'Thread-2',target = display, args=('thread-2',host,ports[1],'player2'))
    thread3 = Thread(name = 'Thread-3',target = display, args=('thread-3',host,ports[2],'player3'))

    thread1.daemon = True
    thread2.daemon = True
    thread3.daemon = True   

    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread3.start() 

    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()
    thread3.join()

main()
```

Please help me how I can send the meta data as I am new to socket programming in python

Comment: You do realize that UDP is _unreliable_? Messages can be dropped and can arrive in a different order than they were sent.